# .NET CultureInfo Localized DisplayName

Tags: c#, .net, localization, globalization

If I write this code:

```
var displayName = new CultureInfo("ja-JP").DisplayName;
```

The value of `displayName` is:

```
"Japanese (Japan)"
```

Is there a way or a property on a `CultureInfo` instance that will give me the *localized* display name? For example, instead of:

```
"Japanese (Japan)"
```

I want to get:

```
日本語（日本）
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`CultureInfo.NativeName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.nativename(v=vs.110).aspx) property like:

```
var nativeName = new CultureInfo("ja-JP").NativeName;
```

This will give you: `nativeName = "日本語 (日本)"`